# Calling threads through COM interop

Tags: c#, com, vb6, task, com-interop

I get an error whenever I try to call a C# thread from Visual Basic classic through COM. The Error says that generic types cannot be marshaled which is weird since there are no generics involved.

COM interface:

```
[Guid("C8B306A5-980D-4226-8130-5E2E0F710FC2")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface comInterface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    Task firstTask();
}
```

Implementation:

```
[Guid("0D5E5234-B1C0-4CFA-9B35-21F091E2E8C4")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("COMproject.implementClass")]
public class implementClass : comInterface{
public async Task firstTask(){
//doSomething
}
```

Call in Vb6:

```
Dim comObject As muhDLL.comInterface
Set comObject = New muhDLL.implementClass
comObject.firstTask
```

I can just create a method which calls the thread in C# and expose the method through COM but then I do get warnings and the code looks ugly in general. Is there any way I can directly call an async task through COM and why does COM not seem to support tasks or am I doing something completly wrong?

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I edited the post. "Generic types cannot be marshaled" exception

Comment: Ok, I am a bit rusty with COM, but it seems logical that it is because of the `Task` I doubt COM can return a Task. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by creating the method as `async`, since as far as I know - COM manages your threads upon calling, and I doubt it uses the benefit of `async await`. I would first try to create the method without returning Task or using async  and checking if it works.

Comment: I´m not too sure what you mean by "I doubt COM can return a Task" since Task doesn´t have a return statement as far as I know.

Comment: All COM methods return an HResult. `HResult = Function(InParam1, InParam2, OutParam1)` VB changes this to look like `OutParam = Function(InParam1, InParam2) with the return going into the error object.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Guid("C8B306A5-980D-4226-8130-5E2E0F710FC2")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface comInterface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    Task firstTask();
}
```

The code above says you want to return a `Task` object to the COM code. Task is an object with properties, methods, etc that represent information about your function that returns void. To return the Task to COM, it would have to be COM visible and all its members would need to be ComVisible as well (I think). I don't know that it is though. Usually you can see a ComVisible attribute on a class when you go it's definition and expand the attributes section above the class, but I don't in this case.

I'm not an expert in this, but I don't believe ComInterop works with async functions like that either. I haven't done a lot of multithreading with COM so I'm not totally sure.

I have an app where I exposed a function that returned void, but it called an async method within it. Then when the async stuff finished, I fired an event I exposed to COM and COM code would handle it.

[Here is a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.85).aspx) on creating events and handling them in COM code

Comment: The whole assembly is COM visible; therefore I don´t have to explicitly declare this attribute on all methods. Thank you for your suggestion, raising events I´ll definitely look into it. I am currently using bool functions to call the async functions, whose return false if an error occured in the async function.